# Google Chrome does not display Google Maps labels correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps

Opened Google Maps on Chrome just to be greeted by this odd picture:

[image]

Firefox on the same machine works without any issues. What might be causing this behavior?

I'm using Version `54.0.2840.71` (64-bit) of `Chrome` (latest) on updated 14.04.

Comment: Use Unity-tweak-tool (install it if you need to) and try to change fonts and/or theme.

Comment: @Jos not sure that solution would work, since it works fine in Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: This has to be a Javascript distro/update issue as mine has just exhibited the same. Thinking too coincidental to be unique to just 2 machines. Looking for a patch soon.

Comment: Same problem here, using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: Same here Chrome  54.0.2840.90 (64-bit)  on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

After updates (on 54.0.2840.100 now) problem automagically disappeared o_O